# j_security_check url problem

Tags: jsf, j-security-check

hope you can help me with this:
I'm working with j_security_check and have this problem

I have a profile page that must be restricted to any unloged user, 
so i add a security constraint in the web.xml file and works fine 
if i try to access by adress bar, this show me the login page perfectly ok

now the problem is that: In my index page example:

> http://localhost/mySite/index.xhtml

have a link

> `<h:commandLink action="user/Profile" />`

this redirect me to profile page ok but the URL still the same

> http://localhost/mySite/index.xhtml

so j_security_check don't show the login page
as far as i've seen j_security_check works with url and jsf don't
and if in the profile page press a link to ex:myImages then now the url says:

> ex: http://localhost/mySite/user/Profile.xhtml

Why is this happend? is there anyway to fix this ??
Thanks in advance

an alternative i've been using is put a like

> `<a href="user/Profile.xhtml" >Profile</a>`

this show me the login page but if i go to the index.xhtml and press profile this don't find the page because redirects me to:

> ex: http://localhost/mySite/user/user/Profile.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:commandLink action="user/Profile" />
```

A `h:commandLink` and `h:commandButton` fires a HTTP POST request (by the `h:form`) to the *current* page which in turn *forwards* to the given resource.

You don't want to use POST for page-to-page navigation. It's not only bad user experience (URL doesn't change, unintuive behaviour when going back/forward in browser history), but also not SEO friendly (searchbots doesn't index POST).

You need to replace it by `h:outputLink` or, as you found out, by a simple `<a>` element if you don't need any JSF-ish features at all.

As to your last problem of going directed to the wrong URL (with duplicated path): this is solved when you use `h:outputLink`. JSF will then take the current context path into account.